# How do I make the argument assignments in Perl

Tags: perl, foreach, arguments

When calling a perl script with:

`myPerlScript --myarg 10 --my2Darg 42x87`.

How do I make the assignments:

```
$myarg = 10;
$my2Darg_x = 42;
$my2Darg_y = 87;
```

if and only if `myarg` and `my2Darg` is valid arguments?

I think I need something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

foreach (@ARGV) {

    if ($_ eq '--myarg') {

        $myarg =
    }
    elsif ($_ eq '--my2Darg') {
        $my2Darg_x =
        $my2Darg_y =
    }
    else {

        print "Not valid argument!!";
    }
}
```

As you can see this code is not complete. Plz. help.

Is there a short way to write `if($_ eq 'text')` (is `if('text')` valid Perl?)?

Comment: Err, those are some significant edits that have been made to the code in the question. Why are you now using `eq` instead of `==` when the problems caused by `==` seemed to be the main point of the question? (although less so now that *Is there a short way to write $_=='text'?* has been deleted from the question text). Likewise, you no longer have variables on the left hand side of your assignments, so additional breakage has been introduced.

Comment: @Quentin: I corrected the test operator when you made me aware of my mistake. I never had any left hand side, as I do not know what to write. -how do I take the next value from `foreach`?

Comment: err… "Left hand side = Right hand side". `my2DArg_x =` will break.

Comment: And I wouldn't take the next value from foreach, I'd use getopt. If I wanted to loop over the options, I'd use numeric indexes.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes I know that `my2DArg_x =` will break. -That is why I write "As you can see this code is not complete" - and why I need help. (I will look at "getopt" when time permit - maybe it is overkill for my purpose)

Comment: You had a scalar on the left hand side before the `$` was edited out!

Comment: `getopt` is **not** overkill for your purpose. Writing your own options parser from scratch is.

Comment: @Quentin: Ok. fxzuz deleted the `$` - I have added them again. I will definitely look at getopt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `Getopt::Long` module, it's on core.

**Script**

```
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my ($arg, $arg_2d);

# prepare format cmd string
GetOptions( "myarg=i" => \$arg, "my2Darg=s" => \$arg_2d);

unless ( $arg && $arg_2d && $arg_2d =~ m{\d+x\d+}i ) {

    print "Usage: $0 --myarg 10 --my2Darg 42x87 \n";
    exit 1;
}

my ($arg_2d_x, $arg_2d_y) = split 'x', $arg_2d;

printf "arg: %s \narg_2d_x: %s \narg_2d_y: %s\n", $arg, $arg_2d_x, $arg_2d_y;
```

**Output**

```
arg: 10 
arg_2d_x: 42 
arg_2d_y: 87
```

Comment: Ok this is cool - I can see that this is the way to go. I just need to figure out how to make the arguments optional with default values - and the general syntax. -But that is a job for me on a rainy day.

Answer (score 3):

`==` is the numerical comparison operator. Use `eq` to compare strings (see [equality operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Equality-Operators) in the manual).

Once you have the string, you can use [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to get a list of the two values.

You should probably use one of the [getopt modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=getopt) instead of looping over `@ARGV`.

Comment: I second the `getopt` recommendation. See [here](http://www.vromans.org/johan/articles/getopt.html) for a brief introduction.